# HashMap to JSONArray and handling the response in jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this HashMap< String,Employee>() object and I convert it to JSONArray as below

```
JSONArray jarray = JSONArray.fromObject(myHashMap);
```

Note that the key in the map is always a numeric literal but its datatype is String.

Below is the code which is used to set json string to the response.

```
response.setContentType("text/text;charset=utf-8");
response.setHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println(jarray.toString());
out.flush();
```

The json string i get is

```
[{"1":{"empAge":32,"empEmail":"name@mail.com","empId":1,"empName":"myname","empTel":"33445"}]
```

how to get the value of empName in map with key value 1?

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/MyApp/TestAction.do",
dataType :"json",
success: function(response){
     alert(response.1[0].empName);// I get java script error in this statement
    },
    error: function(e){
        alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong header:

```
 response.setContentType("text/text;charset=utf-8");
```

Change it to:

```
response.setContentType("application/json;charset=utf-8");
```

currently you are getting it as a string so you cannot use it as an object, once you change the header you'll get it as a json object and would be able to use it.

As a side note, "1" is not a very good key, if you can replace it to a more descriptive string, I'd suggest you do that.

Comment: I have changed the content type as mentioned and appended a String 'emp' to the key so now the key looks like 'emp1'. Now that the script error is gone and when i tried alerting response.emp1.empName i get 'undefined' msg. Below is the json text i did by System.out [{"emp1":{"empAge":32,"empEmail":"name@mail.com","empId":1,"empName":"myname","empTel":"33445"}]

Comment: Do a console.log() (in javascript) on the response and post what you get

Comment: i dont have any idea as to what the console.log() does. But when i do $.parseJSON(response), the result is null. Does it mean that my json string is invalid? But i have tested the string in jsonlint.com and it asserts the string to be valid.

Comment: console.log logs to the console. If you don't know what it is and you are developing for the web, then you are in a serious problem :) i hope you know what firebug is, if not then look it up and start using it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! i have changed the datatype of empAge and empId to String and now its working fine.